# Could not save XML data to file /home/username/.mysql/workbench/connections.xml

Tags: 18.04, mysql, mysql-workbench

I have installed mysql workbench on Ubuntu 18.04. I'm getting error:

```
[2003] can't connect to database on 127.0.0.1 (111).
```

so I have tried to put `bind-address=127.0.0.1` in `/etc/my.cnf` file but i couldn't find it at that location and it was in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` but it was only read-only. From terminal

```
vi /etc/my.cnf
```

then wrote that and exit from the file (it was new file), i tried to reopen `mysql-workbench` but got new problem at starting

```
 Error while setting up home screen. The error message is: Could not save XML data to file /home/anup/.mysql/workbench/connections.xml
```

after that when i was trying to create a connection got the below problem. now ,i'm not even able create new connection.

```
Exception caught while processing action from home screen: error calling Python module function WbAdmin.autoDetectLocalInstance
```

I uninstalled and then reinstall mysql workbench but nothing worked. I just don't know what happened and how to fix it.

Comment: What is the issue after reinstalling?

Comment: After reinstalling when i am trying to open mysql-workbench following error popping up..  Error while setting up home screen. The error message is: Could not save XML data to file /home/anup/.mysql/workbench/connections.xml

Comment: And after closing the pop up error window when i am trying to connect to database...following exception is occurring...   Exception caught while processing action from home screen: error calling Python module function WbAdmin.autoDetectLocalInstance

Comment: revert the changes has been done in `my.cnf` file, set it as default and see which error it shows. Perhaps, because modification was done in my.cnf file may wrong.

Comment: Changes done but still same problem

Comment: Still same issue means, previous error, `[2003] can't connect to database on 127.0.0.1 (111)` ? and `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` is MySQL database server configuration file. Have you installed mysql server? You need to make necessary changes in file where mysql DB server is installed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ gksu gedit /usr/share/applications/mysql-workbench.desktop**
```

Change relevant lines to:

```
Exec=gksu mysql-workbench
Terminal=false
Type=application
```